# Tab doesn't select text in user name field on Windows 10 login screen

Tags: windows-10, login-screen

Tabbing between fields on the login screen used to select all the text in a field, so you could just type over the old text, without having to first delete it. It still does that for the Password field, but not for the User Name field.

Example:
Let's say that I type my username to login to a Windows 10 machine. Then I tab to type in my password. I type half of my password, but then realize that I've typed my username incorrectly. I shift-tab back to the username field, but all the text isn't highlighted; the cursor is at the end of my username and I have to backspace a few times (or ctrl+a,del). When I tab back to the password field, all of the text is highlighted, so I can just retype my password without having to delete the partial text.

This inconsistency was not present in Windows 7, and likely not 8, though I can't confirm that right now.

Does anyone have a solution so that tabbing on the login screen always selects the text in all fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This functionality in logonui may have been a convenience change for a great deal of others, since they may wish to only edit a few characters. Since you already used the hotkey of shift+tab you could ctrl+a to highlight the text. Beyond that, I hope this doesn't come up so much that it's a huge issue.

Comment: I agree that they probably made the change as a convenience for the majority, though I tend to not fit the mold. Since I type usernames and passwords so fast, muscle memory and all that, it's usually faster for me to retype than to edit. As you say, I do ctrl+a, but was still hoping for an easy switch to revert the feature to my preferred state.